# Adding the day to the name of a logfile

Tags: c#, log4net, appsettings, log4net-configuration

Using log4net to store text in file. from

http://sadi02.wordpress.com/2008/06/29/log4net-tutorial-in-c-net-how-can-i-show-log-in-a-file/

In the appsettings file:

```
 <param name="File" value="C:\Try\logger\logger\bin\Debug\log.txt" />
```

is used to create the file. Problem is the file will already exist from previous runs; how can I add additional info to the filename e.g.

```
 <param name="File" 
        value="C:\Try\logger\logger\bin\Debug\log + "Monday" + .txt" />
```

Here Monday flags saying it is missing required whitespace?

**UPDATE**
**Thanks for the duplicate Ive used it to add:**

```
  <param name="DatePattern" value="dd.MM.yyyy'.log'" />
  <param name="File" 
         value="C:\Try\logger\logger\bin\Debug\log + DatePattern + .txt" />
```

but now the file is saved as

```
log + DatePattern + .txt
```

why wont it save the actual date?

Answer (score 2):

You can use log4net.Util.PatternString to do this, in your case do the following:

```
 <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="C:\Try\logger\logger\bin\Debug\log%date{dd}.txt" />
```

For further info please refer to the documentation:

[Documentation of log4net.Util.PatternString class](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/?topic=html/T_log4net_Util_PatternString.htm)